# animated ng-show with custom directive having tempate from partials causes initial fadeout

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I use my custom directive with not inlined template together with animated `ng-show="false"` on the same element simultaneously then on page initialization I see element fading out even it should have never been displayed. Is it a bug in AngularJS, my code or is it a feature?

How can I work it around without either inlining template or wrapping `<div my-directive></div>` to `<div ng-show='shown'>...</div>`? I would like to have it working just with `<div ng-show='shown' my-directive></div>`.

Please see example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/jAacmYSN8NksAOlCNHLy. First two examples work correctly. The third one doesn't work as expected - you can see the problem just after pushing "Run" button.

Comment: I'm going to say feature. The reason that one and two work is because angular does not render the child content because it is supposed to be hidden. On the third though the template content is rendered and then hidden. If you use ng-if it behaves like one and two.

Comment: Thanks. I've played with ng-if but then I've lost animation capability.

Comment: Alright, forked the plunker and got you an easy fix. http://plnkr.co/edit/dNcVVJ8KmqH9PW24vlID?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Brandon! I've further simplified it so the solution with my sample was to replace `class='animate-show'` with `ng-class="'animate-show'"` :-)